# Instantaneous phase voltages of 3 phase WYE load

Tags: voltage, power, phase

If phase 1 instantaneous voltage is 100 v and decreasing what are the other phase instantaneous voltages if the max voltage of phase 1 is 170 V? Frequency equals 60 HZ. (60 Cps).

- I do not understand this question as there is no time given for when it is at 100 V. How would you find the time that the voltage is at 100 V to find the other instantaneous voltage values?

Comment: The relationship between the instantaneous voltage value, 100 v and decreasing and the peak value, 170 v, along with the frequency tells you the relationship between the time when the voltage is at 100 v and the time when the voltage is at its peak. Make a sketch of the waveforms showing the phase relationship. You should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

It's geometry. Assume that the phase relationship of each phase is 120 degrees (360 / 3) and solve the triangle.

[image]

Frequency or time plays no part in this.